# Push notification from PC to android without Google cloud messaging(GCM)

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

### Push notification from PC to android without Google cloud messaging(GCM)

I would like to create close notification service, means i want to get the communication with each other in my own network.

---

I like the way to get notification by using GCM but i have been assigned to do this thing without GCM (need to create something like GCM to be a messaging service instead of GCM). So, I want to ask if there any way to do this?
or it would be great if there have some any tutorial to create messaging service instead using  GCM.
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search i found this solution --> http://www.rabbitmq.com/

I didn't test my self, but you cand find a tutorial here http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/

Just say that GCM is prepared to have some consideration with device battery. It is possible that these workarounds for push notifications don't be so nice with devices

Comment: to use rabbitMQ i suggest to start by java tutorials, and then go for android. By the way, the support/documentation to use rMQ for android is weak, to make something more robust you need to dig by yourself.

Comment: What is RabbitMQ use for? Is it the same like pushbots.com  ?? ?

Comment: "RabbitMQ is a messaging broker - an intermediary for messaging. It gives your applications a common platform to send and receive messages, and your messages a safe place to live until received." As I understand, it works very similar as GCM, and pushbots.com too, but pushbots seems to be a comercial solution which offer other things like notify by tweets and some analytics data.

Comment: I see... but I gotta create a messaging service to be receive message from client and send to the other client. So, if I use RabbitMQ means I use other messaging service, right? any way else that i should do?